# pathml installation on Mac

Tags: python

I have just finished reading a [scientific paper on computational pathology](https://mcr.aacrjournals.org/content/early/2022/01/04/1541-7786.MCR-21-0665) and I would like to try out the software described. It is called "pathml".

How can I install it on my Mac?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found here the [pathml source code](https://github.com/Dana-Farber-AIOS/pathml) and I followed the pip installation instructions. Worked immediately!